# Is there any advantage to using XAML over BPMN?

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, business-process-management, bpmn

I've been asked to research embeddable workflow engines in both .Net and Java.

The Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) product uses XAML for designing workflows.  The two Java workflow engines I'm looking at (jBPM, Activiti) both use BPMN 2.0.

I've read there are some [weaknesses in BPMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation#Weaknesses_of_BPMN).

**Is there anything compelling about XAML over BPMN as a business process modeling language?**

Edit: Looking aside the obvious differences in platforms (.net/java), tooling, etc. and focusing on the modeling languages (XAML and BPMN)

Comment: Although this question is closed as not constructive, I myself was asking the same question in my mind. I think it would have been a good discussion point. I guess it is open for debate and extended discussion. Pity.